# What's the best way to generate an API reference document using a Rails routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes, rake, introspection

I am trying to document the API for my Rails application and I can't help but wonder if there is a better way to generate an XML file based on my routes.rb file.  I'm envisioning something similar to the output of `rake routes` but in a more friendly, XML type format.  Corey has some interesting ideas about using reflection/introspection on the routes file [here](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/guides-tips-and-tutorials/introspection-and-reflection-for-rails-controllers) but it's not quite what I need.

Please tell me this is a solved problem and I'm not the first one to think of this.  :)

Comment: Could you refine the question if you have additional requirements or plans for the API reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake routes` is a normal rake task:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake

Perhaps you could learn relevant things from it and write a new task for generating routes in a (-cough-) more friendly xml format. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really find an exact match for what you're looking for (which surprised me too) but you might look at [a sitemap gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) to get started with what you want. This might have to be custom code ... sadly

Comment: Considering `rake routes` is 28 lines of code it might not be so monumental task.

Comment: He's looking to generate an XML file to document the API. I guessed that part of the requirements would be that the entire rake:routes file wasn't part of the API. Also, the rake file pipes to STOUT and he wants an XML file. I just figured a sitemap generator was a good place to start.

Comment: It is a good example of complex specification satisfying thing. Note that the code in `rake routes` doesn't output all the routes either. Generating the XML with Builder and writing it to a file is a no-brainer.